# How to rename a section in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've created a report in Crystal Report 2008 Version 12.3.3.812 (together with Visual Studio 2010 Professional Version 10.0.30319.1).
In earlier versions of CR there was a properties window, where the name of the section could be set.
I didn't find any possibility to change the section name in CR 2008, the sections are now simply named Section1,  GroupHeaderSection1, DetailSection1, GroupFooterSection1, Section2

It is necessary that a name for each section can be given, since i use this when printing the report to suppress unwanted sections.

`*additional info*`
If i open the report from Visual Studio 2005 which loads the CR 2008 Report Designer inside Visual Studio I'm able to set the section names as in older Versions. So maybe the problem is only in the "external" CR 2008 Report Designer. Any idea on how I would get VS 2010 to open up CR Designer inside VS2010?

Answer (score 2):

If you click on a section and then look at the properties window in VS 2010 at the top there is a (Name) property. Just edit that and the name will update the section.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the report opens up in an external report designer, not inside VS 2010 as in older versions. If you can tell me how to get CR to open up inside VS2010 than this might be a solution.

Comment: On the SAP website there is the CR2008 for VS 2010. Download and install and give it a try?

Comment: Could you please give me a link where i can download that? I've downloaded my version from https://websmp130.sap-ag.de/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm and there are no files available if i select Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010. I wasn't able to find anything useful on the SAP website itself (except for the downloadlink to a 30 day trial)

Comment: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/crystalreports-dotnet 
Bottom of the page under Knowledge Center.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used the XI version, but I've never heard of changing the names of sections. Normally, to suppress certain sections, just use the methods in the Section Expert.

Comment: Yes i know i can use these methods, but what i want is to suppress the sections on runtime. I am running my ASP.NET Application and want to print a report and suppress some section. Therefore i loop through the sections of the report and identify them by their name. That way i can have a setting in a database defining whether the report should be a short or long one (for example). But i need a possibility to set the names by myself, because otherwise they are just generic Details1, Details2 and if i insert new ones later,the whole naming gets mixed up and my code suppresses the wrong sections.

Comment: That makes complete sense.  Can't help you with it, though. Maybe someone else can.